# Shinyinput to select column for create table

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have table `name = t1` and `shinyinput = input$select1`.
I want to select dynamic data column by shiny input  from `t1` table to create a new data table to plot

```
   a <- c(t1$yie)
   q <- c(t1$qty)
   date <- c(t1$date)
   mydata <- data.table(a,q,date)
```

I have try  `a <- c(t1$",input$select1,")` and   `a <- c(t1$/'",input$select1,"/')` but not work

thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you want to do `t1[[input$select1]]`

Comment: @bobbel This work so good , Thanks you to much